# Rails 4 hstore defining datatypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, psql, hstore

So I know that hstore only stores in string either key and especially value. I'm looking for a way to set their datatypes. Is there a way in rails or hstore to do this?

So far what I did was to override the getters and depending on the datatype I want. This is what I have so far:

```
class ModelWithHstore < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :properties, :some_boolean_field, :some_integer_field, :some_datetime_field

  validate :validate_range

  def some_boolean_field
    return if self[:properties].nil? || self[:properties][__method__.to_s].nil?

    if [true, 'true', '1'].include? self[:properties][__method__.to_s]
      return true
    elsif [false, 'false', '0'].include? self[:properties][__method__.to_s]
      return false
    end

    self[:properties][__method__.to_s]
  end

  def some_integer_field
    return if self[:properties].nil? || self[:properties][__method__.to_s].nil?

    self[:properties][__method__.to_s].to_i
  end

  def some_datetime_field
    return if self[:properties].nil? || self[:properties][__method__.to_s].nil?

    DateTime.strptime(self[:properties][__method__.to_s].to_s, '%F %T')
  end

  private

  def validate_range
    errors.add(:some_integer_field, "value out of range") if !some_integer_field.between?(10, 90)
  end
end
```

And since they are getters. I think they are being used too in validators and some other places. But I really am not sure if something like this already exists or is there a better way to implement this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [hstore_accessor](https://github.com/devmynd/hstore_accessor) gem